# How to change the user_login by the usermeta field of the same User

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

How to change the user_login by the usermeta field of the same User.

I need to change the Wordpress login by the usermeta mat field of all users in a Wordpress installation with over a thousand users.

What's the best way to do this?

I Try

```
UPDATE `wp_users`
SET user_login = (
    SELECT meta_value from `wp_usermeta` WHERE user_id = ID and meta_key ="_mat"
)
WHERE ID = ID;
```

0 rows affected

But without success

```
    SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta as a 
join wp_users as b ON a.user_id = b.ID 
WHERE a.user_id = ID and a.meta_key = "_mat"
```

Shows several values

I'm not finding the syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're trying to use `ID` in the `WHERE` but it is not defined in that context

try to join `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` on `user_id` and use `UPDATE` to set `user_login` to `meta_value` where `meta_key` is `"_mat"`

```
UPDATE wp_users
JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
SET wp_users.user_login = wp_usermeta.meta_value
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = '_mat';
```

Ps. be sure to back up your database before making any changes + test this query on a staging environment before running it on production

Comment: glad it was helpful~~